# output value is always returning something that is not correct

Tags: java

I'm currently coding my project and I seem to have everything down except my results for Gross Pay is always coming out as 0.0 and I don't know where or how to fix it. These are my codes, it's supposed to print out 
How many employees are there? 1

Worked, Pay Rate, and Employee name separated by a space: 37.25 15.5 Tony Stark 
Employee Name: Tony Stark
Hours Worked:       37.25
Pay Rate:           15.50
Gross Pay:          $577.38

```
public class Project3 {
public static void main(String[] theArgs) {

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  double hours = 0.0;
  double payRate = 0.0;
  int employeeCount = getEmployeeCnt(console);
  double grossPay = getGrossPay(payRate, hours);
  processEmployeePay(console, employeeCount, grossPay, hours, payRate);

}
  public static int getEmployeeCnt(Scanner theConsole) {
    System.out.print("How many employees are there? ");
    return theConsole.nextInt();
  }
  public static String processEmployeePay(Scanner theConsole, int 
  employeeCount, double grossPay, double hours, double payRate) {
  String empFirst = "";
  String empLast = "";
  for(int i = 1; i <= employeeCount; i++) {
     System.out.print("Enter Hours Worked, Pay Rate, and Employee Name separated by a space: ");
     hours = theConsole.nextDouble();
     payRate = theConsole.nextDouble();
     empFirst = theConsole.next();
     empLast = theConsole.next();
     System.out.println("\t Employee Name: " + "\t" + empFirst + " " + empLast);
     System.out.println("\t Hours Worked: " + "\t" + hours);
     System.out.println("\t Pay Rate: " + "\t" + payRate);
     System.out.println("\t Gross Pay: " + "\t" + grossPay);
  }
  return "";
}
  public static double getGrossPay(double payRate, double hours) {
     double result = 0.0;
     if (hours >= 48) {
        result = (2 * hours * payRate);
     } else{
       if (hours <= 48) {
          result = (1.5 * hours * payRate);
       }  else {
            if (hours > 40) {
              result = (1.5 * hours * payRate);
          }
              else { 
                if (hours <= 40) {
                  result = (hours * payRate);
                }
              }
            }
        }
   return result;
}


}
```

Comment: Are we suppose to guess your code?

Comment: i added a picture but for some reason its not showing

Comment: Post the code as text, not as picture. Also add expected and actual output.

Comment: When you multiply any number with `0` then you will get `0` as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable class level, because its local it has default values.
And setting value in `processEmployeePay` won't set the value because java is pass by value.

See [java-is-strictly-pass-by-value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-31-java-is-strictly-pass-by-value/)

Change it like below:

```
class Your-Class{
   private static double payRate = 0.0
   ... 
   Other fields

   public static processEmployeePay(Scanner sc){
    payRate = sc.nextDouble();
    // others too
   }

}
```